# Give name to TemporaryFolder JUnit4

Tags: java, junit4

Consider the following scenario:

```
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder
import org.junit.Rule

class SampleTest {
    @Rule TemporaryFolder testProjectDir = new TemporaryFolder(new File("/tmp/tempFolders"))
    ....
}
```

Using the code above, the temporary folders for every test case will be created inside: /tmp/tempFolders. However, the naming is randomly assigned, something like: `/tmp/tempFolders/junit2384171115406894976/`.

Is it possible to give a name, for example: NamedFolder, so that all tests will start out with having `/tmp/tempFolders/NamedFolder` as their TemporaryFolder location.

Comment: Why? That defeats the purpose of it being a temporary folder (what if you wanted to execute multiple tests simultanously and all used the same folder).

Comment: @JoachimSauer For multiple executions, it will be problematic. However, I am looking to run tests one by one, and the temporary files that I am testing are supposed to be in a specific location. Therefore, I need to create a temporary folder with a specific name.

Comment: That sounds like you don't want to use a `TemporaryFolder` at all, since you want to disable basically everything that makes it a `TemporaryFolder`. Do you want it to also not delete the files after running?

Comment: @JoachimSauer after a test, it should be deleted. Then for another test, the same location is used.